# How to save/change text of 'QLineEdit' in 'QSettings' and get on 'QPushButton's' call

Tags: python, pyside2, qsettings

I want to save/change my 'QLineEdit' text in my app and get again by using 'QPushButton' on some specific position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is to associate the information with a key, in the following example I show how the text is saved when the text is modified and then the text is retrieved by pressing the button.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.m_le.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self.m_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press Me")
        self.m_button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_le)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_button)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        settings.setValue("text", text)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def onClicked(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        text = settings.value("text")
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```